# Why does returning a vector initialized with curly braces within normal brackets cause a compilation error?

Tags: c++, c++11

I just wrote a simple method to return a vector made with two int arguments. However, when I return the initialized int vector within normal brackets, it causes compilation error.

```
std::vector<int> getVec(int x, int y)
{
    return({x, y}); // This causes compile error
    return {x, y};  // This is fine
}
```

The error message says:

```
q.cpp: In function ‘std::vector<int> getVec(int, int)’:
q.cpp:8:21: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
    8 |         return({x, y});
      |                     ^
      |                     ;
q.cpp:8:15: error: could not convert ‘((void)0, y)’ from ‘int’ to ‘std::vector<int>’
    8 |         return({x, y});
      |               ^~~~~~~~
      |               |
      |               int
```

Comment: `({x, y});` Why should that work? That never works, anywhere.

Comment: I expected it to work like some other return statements, say like, "return(x);" which is the same as "return x;", and x is some local variable of almost any type.

Comment: Putting the value you return between parentheses is pointless anyway, it makes the `return` statement look like a function call which it isn't.

Comment: @sol the parantheses in `return()` have nothing to do with `return` itself, they have to do with the value which is being returned so `return(x)` is the same as `return (x)`. `({x,y})` is not the same as `{x,y}`.

Comment: *"x is some local variable of almost any type"* - Naked curly braces have no type

Comment: By the way, what's with the tag spam? Is it really about *all* those standard revisions

Comment: @Tharsalys I think the idea is that an *expression*, according to the C++ grammar, can be another *expression* in round parentheses (e.g., whenever you can say `5` you can say `(5)`, e.g. when you return a value). The parentheses don't change the type. Now a *braced initializer list*, e.g. `{5}`,  is not an expression (as others said, it doesn't have a type). It is its own grammatical specimen. (The `5` inside it is an expression though, so `{(5)}` and `{5}` should be equivalent.) (ctd.)

Comment: (ctd...) Consequently, the grammar of a return statement had to be amended for initializer lists. The grammar now is "return expr-or-braced-init-list *opt* ;". expr-or-braced-init-list, unsurprisingly, is either an expression or a braced init list; two different things ;-). Putting a braced init list in parentheses is simply ungrammatical: For example, you also cannot put keywords in parentheses.

Comment: *"return(x);" which is the same as "return x;"*  Those are not the same, semantically.  Fortunately, the first one optimizes well even with optimizations disabled.  But can cause problems, such as discovered.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [return statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return):

> - return expression(optional) ;   (1)
> - return braced-init-list ; (2)

Remember the `{..}` is not an expression, has no type. There exist some contexts which allow `{..}` to be deduced in some type.

There is a special case for `return {..}` (2) and uses copy-list-initialization to construct the return value of the function.

In `return ({x, y})`, we go in (1), and `{x, y}` still has no type, no special cases for `({..})`. So the error.

Comment: Since the first error reported is a syntax error, I think that type considerations are not relevant to explaining the error.

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
return {x, y};
```

`{x, y}` is a `std::initializer_list<int>`, so when your compiler sees this, it can deduce the type into:

```cpp
std::vector<int>{std::initializer_list<int>{x, y}};
```

But:

```cpp
return ({x, y});
```

This isn't systax correct:

```cpp
std::vector<int>({std::initializer_list<int>{x, y}});
```

The compiler doesn't know hơ to deduce this, so it gives a compilation error.

Comment: `{x, y}` is a `std::initializer_list<int>`, so the explicit statement is `return std::vector<int>{std::initializer_list<int>{x, y} };`.

Comment: "`{x, y}` is a `std::initializer_list<int>`". More complicated than that, it can be deduced as `std::initializer_list<int>` but [list_initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Explanation) might choose other constructors (and so `{x, y}` would not be `std::initializer_list<int>`).